# How to draw histograms under a curve?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

Suppose we have a function (like pdf of a normal distribution), and we want to approximate it with histograms under the function. I wanna specify the number of bins and draw histograms under the curve. How is it possible to do in Python? For example, a graph like below, but all spikes are under the curve, and the number of bins is a parameter.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a coding service. Please read the following documentation, then [edit], and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), & [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Always provide a [mre] with **code, data, errors, current & expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)** & **you're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and show your effort**.

Comment: Thank you JohanC. That is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `pdf` to decide the heights of the bars:

```py
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np
N = 20
x = np.linspace(norm.ppf([0.001, 0.999]), N)
y = norm.pdf(x)
```

Each center of a bar will be just as high as the `pdf`, so the bars will cut the curve. To only touch the curve, one could calculate the `pdf` at the lowest point, being `x + width/2` for positive points. As the `pdf` is symmetric, `abs` can be used to create a single expression for both positive and negative x-values.

Here is an animation created via the [celluloid](https://pypi.org/project/celluloid/) library.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy.stats import norm
from celluloid import Camera

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 2))
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15, left=0.1, right=0.97)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
camera = Camera(fig)
x0, x1 = norm.ppf([0.001, 0.999])
x_pdf = np.linspace(x0, x1, 1000)
y_pdf = norm.pdf(x_pdf)
for N in range(10, 80):
    ax.plot(x_pdf, y_pdf, 'r', lw=2)
    x_bar = np.linspace(x0, x1, N)
    width = x_bar[1]-x_bar[0]
    y_bar = norm.pdf(np.abs(x_bar) + width/2)
    ax.bar(x_bar, y_bar, width=width, fc='DeepSkyBlue', ec='k')
    ax.margins(x=0)
    ax.set_ylabel('probability density')
    camera.snap()
animation = camera.animate(interval=600)
animation.save('gaussian_histogram.gif')
plt.show()
```

[image: histogram along gaussian pdf]

PS: Here is a list of related questions (collected by @TrentonMcKinney), where you can find additional explanation and ideas:

- [How to add a standard normal pdf over a seaborn histogram](/questions/52908925/how-to-add-a-standard-normal-pdf-over-a-seaborn-histogram)
- [Fitting a Normal distribution to 1D data](/questions/20011122/fitting-a-normal-distribution-to-1d-data)
- [How do I draw a histogram for a normal distribution using python matplotlib?](/questions/61940618/how-do-i-draw-a-histogram-for-a-normal-distribution-using-python-matplotlib)
- [How to plot normal distribution](/questions/10138085/how-to-plot-normal-distribution)

Comment: Thanks, Johan, yeah it is exactly what I am looking for. Done